# How to populate form select with struct data in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to find a way to populate a form select with Go, the data I am trying to populate is taking from a MySQL table, I have already managed to create an array from the rows, I am now looking to populate a select form.

The goal is to be able to select a row from the drop down, to then send a query to delete the selected row from the table.

Below is the code:

HTML

```
                        {{if .Success}}
                           <h1>Your Vehicle has been successfully removed!</h1>
                           <div class="divFlex">
                              <button onclick="location.href = 'Add-Vehicle.html';" class="btn-block frgt_1 btn addV_btn" type="button" value="Add Another Vehicle">Add Vehicle<br>
                              </button>
                              <button onclick="location.href = 'Add-Vehicle.html';" class="btn-block frgt_1 btn addV_btn" type="button" value="Add Another Vehicle">Remove Vehicle</button>
                           </div>
                        {{else}}
                           <form action="/remove" method="POST" source="custom" name="form">
                              <input type="hidden" name="xss-token" value=""/>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <div>
                                    <label class="addV_label">Select Vehicle&nbsp;</label>
                                    <select id="places" name="places">
                                    {{range .}}
                                    <option value="{{.Value}}" id="{{.Id}}" {{if .Selected}}selected{{end}}>{{.Text}}</option>
                                    {{end}}
                                    </select>
                                    <select name="select" class="form-control loginInput2" required="required">
                                       <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                 <button class="btn-block frgt_1 btn addV_btn" type="submit" value="remove">REMOVE</button>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        {{end}}
```

Main.go

```
func RemoveVehicle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("Remove-Vehicle.html"))

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:WgFl3f8218!@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/my_db")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection Failed.")
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()

    // Query the DB
    var car Vehicle
    sqlStatement := `SELECT * FROM Vehicle`
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStatement)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var carSlice []Vehicle
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&car.Id, &car.Date, &car.Brand, &car.Model, &car.Mileage, &car.Year, &car.rented, &car.Dayrate)
        carSlice = append(carSlice, car)
    }

    fmt.Println(carSlice)

    // insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO vehicle(id, date, brand, model, mileage, manufactured, rented, dayrate) VALUES ( ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ?)", id.String(), brand_, model_, mileage_, year_, dayrate_)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err.Error())
    // }
    // defer insert.Close()

    // tmpl.Execute(w, struct {
    //  Success bool
    //  Brand   string
    //  Model   string
    //  Year    int64
    //  Mileage int64
    //  Dayrate int64
    // }{true, brand_, model_, year_, mileage_, dayrate_})
}
```

Another issue I see is that the form method being POST, as I've seen a few examples in which the form method is GET.

I need to be able to populate select on page load, and then remove the matching option from the table.

Comment: Bro, your question is not clear. I can't got the problem or bug in your code, you need to edit your question for reader to find key point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both POST and GET method but they serve for different purposes.

[GET and POST explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Also you can check the link below to see how POST and GET requests are handled in Go server with built-in http package.

[Get and Post request handled](https://www.golangprograms.com/example-to-handle-get-and-post-request-in-golang.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).